# ASP.NET MVC 5 EF6 Structure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

after thinking a lot about this we are going to give a try to ASP.NET MVC to upgrade a complex Web Forms project we have. Since we are new in MVC we have a lot of doubts.

Our project has an administration panel or backend with more than 70 pages and then a public site where we show all the information.

1) We are going to use MVC 5 and EF6 with database first. We love the way we can create all the entities without writting a single line and also how can we update the model when we change the database.

We have seen how you can create the CRUD operations with the scaffolding feature. This way also we save a lot of time, but is this the best way to do it?

2) At web forms we had different layers and then, in the presentation layer we have an "admin" folder where the backend pages are. The public pages are at the root folder.

How do you manage this in MVC? Since MVC uses VIEWS how can we separate both parts? Also, different parts use same Models, but what about controllers?

3) Is it storing the Models and Controllers in their folders the best structure? We used to separate the project in different layers, but that was for Web Forms, we don't know which is the best approach in MVC, What do you think? 
If you separate in different projects, could you show us an example?

4) Also we used Telerik ASP.NET Rad Controls for Web Forms. Those controles are great for Web Forms and we also have the license for MVC, but are those good to use in MVC? Are necessary?
We have a lot of grids where we have to make some operations, show images, have buttons, upload images...
Are there any other options?

Thanks for helping. We are new in MVC but we hope we can learn fast because it seems amazing what you can do.

Comment: There are tons of possible answers for your post. You should ask specific questions to have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) We are going to use MVC 5 and EF6 with database first. We love the
>   way we can create all the entities without writting a single line and
>   also how can we update the model when we change the database.
>
> We have seen how you can create the CRUD operations with the
>   scaffolding feature. This way also we save a lot of time, but is this
>   the best way to do it?

You do not want to use scaffolding feature. As you said in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26242025/296861) that your have over 200 pages of Web Form. If so, you want to split the application into multiple layers with loosely coupled.

> 2) At web forms we had different layers and then, in the presentation
>   layer we have an "admin" folder where the backend pages are. The
>   public pages are at the root folder. How do you manage this in MVC?
>   Since MVC uses VIEWS how can we separate both parts? Also, different
>   parts use same Models, but what about controllers?

You can use Area.

> 3) Is it storing the Models and Controllers in their folders the best
>   structure? We used to separate the project in different layers, but
>   that was for Web Forms, we don't know which is the best approach in
>   MVC, What do you think? If you separate in different projects, could
>   you show us an example?

Look at open source projects such as NopCommerce, Orchard or Umbraco.

> 4) Also we used Telerik ASP.NET Rad Controls for Web Forms. Those
>   controles are great for Web Forms and we also have the license for
>   MVC, but are those good to use in MVC? Are necessary? We have a lot of
>   grids where we have to make some operations, show images, have
>   buttons, upload images... Are there any other options?

Telerik has Kendo UI. If you have DevCraft Ultimate, you can use Kendo UI
Professional which has MVC wrapper for Kendo UI. Basically, wrapper let you use HTML Helpers instead of hand coding JavaScripts.